# How to check if ExecutorService is "healthy" and working?

Tags: java, threadpool

I'm developing a gui-less desktop application for my company that is planned to be always running in the background retrieving info from websites (through HtmlUnit) and updating some rows in the data base.
I'm using a ExecutorService to submit tasks where the web site is loaded so I can set a timeout. This way:

```
private ExecutorService taskExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
private long timeout = 60000L;

private Page loadSite(Loader<Page> c) {
    Page page;
    Future<Page> result = taskExecutor.submit(c);
    try {
        page = result.get(timeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    } catch (TimeoutException | ExecutionException | InterruptedException ex) {
        close();
        result.cancel(true);
        throw new HandledWebException(ex);
    }

    return page.getEnclosingWindow().getEnclosedPage();
}
```

The questions are:

- Should I check if my `taskExecutor` object is able to schedule a task before the `submit` call, and reinstantiate it if necessary? (The prolonged execution time seems like a threat to me)
- Do I have to shutdown and reinstantiate the `taskExecutor` if the submitted task fails to complete?

Answer (score 0):

**1) Should I check if my taskExecutor object is able to schedule a task before the submit call, and reinstantiate it if necessary?**

**2) Do I have to shutdown and reinstantiate the taskExecutor if the submitted task fails to complete?**

For both the question no need

**public static ExecutorService newFixedThreadPool(int nThreads)**

> Creates a thread pool that reuses a fixed number of threads operating off a shared unbounded queue. At any point, at most nThreads threads will be active processing tasks. If additional tasks are submitted when all threads are active, they will wait in the queue until a thread is available. **If any thread terminates due to a failure during execution prior to shutdown, a new one will take its place if needed to execute subsequent tasks. The threads in the pool will exist until it is explicitly shutdown.**